# Adding audio to picture: video too long even when using -shortest

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to combine an audio (.wav) file and picture file (.png) into a video file. The video's length should be the same length as the input audio. Also, the output video should be youtube-friendly (be able to upload to YouTube).

I've tried a couple commands, but the duration of the video file produced is always way too long.

The audio file has a length `00:00:10.71`.

### Command 1

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i 000.png -i 000.wav -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 0  -shortest out.mp4
```

output:

```
$ ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i 000.png -i 000.wav -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 0  -shortest out.mp4
ffmpeg version n4.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181127
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[png_pipe @ 0x561e7bc1e600] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from '000.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 3937:3937 DAR 16:9], 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '000.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:10.71, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 5.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] 264 - core 157 r2945 72db437 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=8 psy=0 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1 fps, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=   25 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     168kB time=00:00:24.00 bitrate=  57.3kbits/s speed=28.9x    
video:63kB audio:103kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.409398%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] frame I:1     Avg QP: 0.00  size: 61676
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] frame P:24    Avg QP: 0.00  size:    76
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] mb I  I16..4: 88.8%  0.0% 11.2%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:100.0%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] coded y,u,v intra: 8.5% 7.6% 7.5% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  1%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 55% 26% 11%  3%  2%  1%  1%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x561e7bc6dbc0] kb/s:20.32
[aac @ 0x561e7bc6fe80] Qavg: 10368.243
```

The video ends up with a length of `00:00:25.00`. [full ffprobe output](https://hastebin.com/juniyofiwe.bash)

### Command 2

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 000.png -i 000.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
```

output:

```
$ ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 000.png -i 000.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
ffmpeg version n4.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181127
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[png_pipe @ 0x559a83ee3640] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from '000.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 3937:3937 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '000.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:10.71, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] 264 - core 157 r2945 72db437 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[aac @ 0x559a83f33a40] Too many bits 12288.000000 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=  324 fps= 46 q=-1.0 Lsize=     230kB time=00:00:12.84 bitrate= 146.9kbits/s speed=1.83x    
video:118kB audio:103kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.943480%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] frame I:2     Avg QP: 9.45  size: 45012
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] frame P:82    Avg QP:10.08  size:   120
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] frame B:240   Avg QP:12.67  size:    85
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] consecutive B-frames:  1.2%  0.0%  0.0% 98.8%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] mb I  I16..4: 87.4%  0.0% 12.6%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.8%  L0:61.0% L1:39.0% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] coded y,u,v intra: 8.4% 0.1% 0.1% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] i16 v,h,dc,p: 95%  3%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 43% 16% 18%  4%  4%  5%  4%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] ref P L0: 95.9%  2.4%  1.4%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] ref B L0: 28.9% 71.1%
[libx264 @ 0x559a83f32480] kb/s:74.29
[aac @ 0x559a83f33a40] Qavg: 60199.988
```

The video ends up with length `00:00:12.96`, still more than the target `00:00:10.71`. Also, processing takes longer. [full ffprobe output](https://hastebin.com/lavegavoye.bash)

### Command 3

```
$ ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i 000.png -i 000.wav -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 0 out.mp4
```

The duration is fine for this one: `00:00:10.77`. This one is a lot faster than the others to process. The output video isn't youtube-friendly though, likely because it only has 1 frame. [Full ffprobe output](https://hastebin.com/lazacewefo.bash)

Why is this happening and how do I get the video to match the length of the input audio?

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way to ensure a desired length for an output is to specify `-t X` on the output.

But if you need adaptive limiting of the output duration, use

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 5 -i 000.png -i 000.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 500M out.mp4`

The `fflag` is applied deeper in the processing pipeline and should be used in conjunction with the `-shortest` switch. The `max_interleave_delta` with a high value is set to avoid writing packets already queued for output.